# for the first time this line console.log("alphabet--->" + alphabet); is printing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, hash

- I am new to js.
- I am analysing a simple code.
- not sure how it works.
- for the first time this line     console.log("alphabet--->" + alphabet); is printing  undefined   counts[alphabet]--->undefined
- can you tell me why its printing undefined.
- for the second time its printing 3 at this line console.log(counts[alphabet] + 1);
- but it should print two right since 1+ 1.
- can you guys explain so that in future I can fix it myself.
- providing my code changes below.

```or-tag-here
var str = "aaabbccccddd";
var arr = str.split("");
var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var alphabet = arr[i];
    console.log("alphabet--->" + alphabet);
        console.log("counts[alphabet]--->" + counts[alphabet]);

    if (counts[alphabet]) 
        {
            counts[alphabet] = counts[alphabet] + 1;
            console.log("inside if--->");
            //console.log("inside if--->" + counts[alphabet] + 1);
            console.log(counts[alphabet] + 1);
        }
    else
    { 
        counts[alphabet] = 1;
        console.log("inside else--->");
        console.log(counts[alphabet]);

        //console.log("inside else--->" + counts[alphabet] + 1);
    }
    //counts[alphabet] = counts[alphabet] ? counts[alphabet] + 1 : 1;
}

console.log('a: ' + counts['a'] + '\n b: ' + counts['b'] + '\n c: ' + counts['c'] + '\n d: ' + counts['d'])
```

output

```or-tag-here
alphabet--->a
  counts[alphabet]--->undefined
  inside else--->
  1
  alphabet--->a
  counts[alphabet]--->1
  inside if--->
  3
  alphabet--->a
  counts[alphabet]--->2
  inside if--->
  4
  alphabet--->b
  counts[alphabet]--->undefined
  inside else--->
  1
  alphabet--->b
  counts[alphabet]--->1
  inside if--->
  3
  alphabet--->c
  counts[alphabet]--->undefined
  inside else--->
  1
  alphabet--->c
  counts[alphabet]--->1
  inside if--->
  3
  alphabet--->c
  counts[alphabet]--->2
  inside if--->
  4
  alphabet--->c
  counts[alphabet]--->3
  inside if--->
  5
  alphabet--->d
  counts[alphabet]--->undefined
  inside else--->
  1
  alphabet--->d
  counts[alphabet]--->1
  inside if--->
  3
  alphabet--->d
  counts[alphabet]--->2
  inside if--->
  4
  a: 3
 b: 2
 c: 4
 d: 3
```

Comment: in your `console.log("counts[alphabet]--->" + counts[alphabet])`, `alphabet` is previously set to `arr[i];` so you're actually saying `console.log("counts[alphabet]--->" + counts[arr[i]])` which doesn't exist in counts yet, so it's undefined

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ hey thanks for your reply...can you give comments its hard to understand...please

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfect! It gives you the correct results at the end. There's just a small mistake in one of the `console.logs()`.

Let's walk through exactly what happens.

Setting up the variables.

```
var str = "aaabbccccddd";
var arr = str.split("");
var counts = {};
```

Loop over `arr`, which is equal to `['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','d']`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

First time inside the loop. Set `alphabet` to `arr[i]` which is `arr[0]` which is `'a'`.

```
var alphabet = arr[i];
```

`counts` is still just an empty object (`{}`) at this point. That means `counts[alphabet]` which is `counts['a']` is '`undefined`'. In JavaScript, `if(undefined)` is the same as `if(false)`, so we jump to the else block.

```
if (counts[alphabet])
```

Inside the else block, we set `counts[alphabet]`, which is `counts['a']`, to `1`. Thus `counts` becomes `{'a': 1}`.

```
counts[alphabet] = 1;
```

Aside from a couple of `console.log()`s there's nothing else to do inside the loop. So `i` changes from `0` to `1` (because of the `i++`). `i < arr.length` which is `1 < 12` is still `true` so we will go through the body of the loop again.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

Second time inside the loop. Set `alphabet` to `arr[i]` which is `arr[1]` which is `'a'`.

```
var alphabet = arr[i];
```

As before, `counts[alphabet]` is `counts['a']` but now `counts['a']` has a value. At the end of the last loop, `counts['a']` was set to `1`. In JavaScript, any number other than `0` is "truthy". This time we will not jump to the else block. We'll do the if block.

```
if (counts[alphabet])
```

We increment `counts[alphabet]` which is `counts['a']`. Before it was `1`. Now it is `2`.

```
counts[alphabet] = counts[alphabet] + 1;
```

Now we come to the line that's giving unexpected output. Per the above line, `counts[alphabet]` which is `counts['a']` is now `2`. And `2` + `1` is `3`, of course. This line will output `3`.

```
console.log(counts[alphabet] + 1);
```

If I understand what you're trying to do, there is no need to add 1 here. Remove the `+ 1` and you should get the expected output.

```
console.log(counts[alphabet]);
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...can you give comments its hard to understand...please

Comment: Yes, I've rewritten the answer with much more detail. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: hey counts empty object is becoming like this {'a': 1} is this is how hash works...can you explain in simple terms...so that I can understand better

Comment: Here's an article that explains how JavaScript objects work in simple terms. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics